# Multiple Azure Function endpoints organized into directory within project

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I have an azure functions directory structure that looks something like this:

```
/azure_function_project
|-- function_1
| |-- __init__.py
| |-- function.json
|-- function_2
| |-- __init__.py
| |-- function.json
```

however for my use it would be very handy to organize into something like this:

```
/azure_function_project
|-- functions_a
| |-- function_a1
| | |-- __init__.py
| | |-- function.json
| |-- function_a2
| | |-- __init__.py
| | |-- function.json
```

where I added an extra directory to contain multiple functions relating to "`functions_a`". Is there any way to ask azure functions to look into these directories when running/publishing?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the [v2 bindings](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-compute-blog/azure-functions-v2-python-programming-model/ba-p/3665168), you may be able to achieve your desired structure, but with the v1 bindings the function folders must be in the top level of the project.

Comment: Is there a way to mix v1 and v2 bindings in a project? Or would I need to convert the whole project to have a v2 binding structure

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible with V1 bindings, so V2 (decorator-style) can be very beneficial for you. However, if have to use older style you can use scriptFile setting to point to another directory or another file (For example, "scriptFile": "../src/funcs/func1.py"). So it can look like this:

```
|-workspace
|  |-func1
|  |  |-function.json
|  |-func2
|  |  |-function.json
|  |-src
|  |  |-funcs
|  |     |-func1.py
|  |     |-func2.py
|  |-host.json
```

And this way you actually can have any source structure you would like.

Comment: Good suggestion, but this would still cause the directories `/func1` and `/func2` to be there. Is there a way to implement a few V2/decorator-style azure functions into a V1 project? Or would the whole project need to be converted to V2